# Iterating through grouped object data in Vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

My data comes from an API as follows

```
{
   "ALBUMS":[
      {
         "ID":"1",
         "TITLE":"'THE BEST OF"
      },
      {
         "ID":"2",
         "TITLE":"MADE IN ENGLAND"
      },
   ],
   "PLAYLISTS":[
      {
         "ID":"5",
         "TITLE":"SUNSET SESSIONS"
      },
       "ID":"2",
         "TITLE":"POOLSIDE SESSIONS"
      }
   ],
}
```

I want to list all titles and types (album or playlist).

The following that I came up with only gives me the first child from albums and playlists:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
 <h1 class="category">{{index}}</h1>
 <h1 class="title">{{item[0].title}}</h1>
```

My desired result would be:

```
Album
The Best Of

Album
Made In England

Playlist
Sunset Sessions

Playlist 
Sunset Sessions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you were missing the second level of your data hierarchy. See the following snippet for an example of how it might work with the data you've provided

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   "ALBUMS":[
      {
         "ID":"1",
         "TITLE":"'THE BEST OF"
      },
      {
         "ID":"2",
         "TITLE":"MADE IN ENGLAND"
      },
   ],
   "PLAYLISTS":[
      {
         "ID":"5",
         "TITLE":"SUNSET SESSIONS"
      },
      {
         "ID":"2",
         "TITLE":"POOLSIDE SESSIONS"
      }
   ],
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <div v-for="album in ALBUMS" :key="album.ID">
   <strong>Album</strong>
     {{album.TITLE}}
   </div>
   <div v-for="playlist in PLAYLISTS" :key="playlist.ID">
     <strong>Playlist</strong>
     {{playlist.TITLE}}
   </div>
</div>
```